# jQuery load() does not work either Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am newbie to jQuery... I intend to load html from another location. When I try to load something bigger, I don't get any error (except 'error') or anything, nothing happens instead. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    var text;
    $("a").on('click', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (loadedData) {
            text = $(loadedData).match(/\d{3}/g);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MvcMethod", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    fulltext: text,
                    filter: ''
                }
            })
                .done(function (tagData) {
                $("#target").html(tagData);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I have a link, full path for a file. The file is exists of course. When I click on it, I would like to pass its content to an MVC action method.

What's wrong, help me pls.

Thanks.

UPDATE: the link maybe points OUT OF domain!

Comment: Is the file on the same domain? What's your href?

Comment: `.match()` is String method, not jQuery method, so `$(loadedData).match(/\d{3}/g)` looks incorrect for me.

Comment: no, the file is out of this domain. So, what would be the solution? I do need to load from anywhere, either from file system too.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: @Quentin `$(loadedData).match(/\d{3}/g)` definitely causes an error, and it is shown in console.

Comment: This line is causing problem.'text = $(loadedData).match(/\d{3}/g);' 'match()' is javascript string method not jquery method.

Comment: @Franziee, do you want to read html file and use that in javascript? Or is it working with `$.ajax` , i mean do you see any 400 or 500 HTTP error?

Comment: @Zeshan oh, common, I have already said it twice.

Comment: Your question title says "jquery load doesn't work". Where are you using `load`?

Comment: unfortunatelly except 'error' I don't get any detailed error. I wrote load() since load() is only a synonym to $.ajax( . I know, the mentioned match() would throw an error, but the program doesn't arrive this point, program doesn't jump into the callback function.